# Build a linear approximation for an unknown function

Tags: algorithm, matlab, numeric

I have some unknown function f(x), I am using matlab to calculate 2000 points on the function graph. I need a piecewise linear function g containing 20 to 30 segments, and it fits best to the original function, how could I do this in an acceptable way? The possible solution space is impossible to traverse and can't think of a good heuristic function to effectively shrink it.

Here is the code from which the function is derived:

```
x = sym('x', 'real'); 
inventory = sym('inventory', 'real'); 
demand = sym('demand', 'real'); 
f1 = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*(-x)*exp(-(x - (demand - inventory)).^2./2); 
f2 = 20/(sqrt(2*pi))*(x)*exp(-(x - (demand - inventory)).^2./2);
expectation_expression = int(f1, x, -inf, 0) + int(f2, x, 0, inf);
```

Comment: Would something like a polynomial or spline fit to your data points work? It would help to know what you have tried ideally showing some code.

Comment: spline may work, however I need to use some already built-in optimizer to do further work based on the function calculated. I don't think the original function share the same shape for some polynomial function. It is derived from the follow integral (which is some expectation):

Comment: x = sym('x', 'real');
    inventory = sym('inventory', 'real');
    demand = sym('demand', 'real');
    f1 = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*(-x)*exp(-(x - (demand - inventory)).^2./2);
    f2 = 20/(sqrt(2*pi))*(x)*exp(-(x - (demand - inventory)).^2./2);
    expectation_expression = int(f1, x, -inf, 0) + int(f2, x, 0, inf);

Comment: The best heuristic is the absolute value of the second derivative. The larger the value, the more curvature the function has, and the more segments you need to get a good approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your idea of a good approximation is, there may be a dynamic programming solution for this.

For example, given 2000 points and corresponding values, we wish to find the piecewise linear approximation with 20 segments which minimizes the sum of squared deviations between the true value at each point and the result of the linear approximation.

Work along the 2000 points from left to right, and at each point calculate for i=1 to 20 the total error from the far left to that point for the best piecewise linear approximation using i segments.

You can work out the values at position n+1 using the values calculated for points to the left of that position - points 1..n. For each value of i, consider all points to its left - say points j < n+1. Work out the error contributions resulting from a linear segment running from point j to point n+1. Add to that the value you have worked out for the best possible error using i-1 segments at point j (or possibly point j-1 depending on exactly you you define your piecewise linear approximation). If you now take the minimum such value over all possible j, you have calculated the error from the best possible piecewise linear approximation using i segments for the first n+1 points.

When you have worked out the best value for the first 2000 points using 20 segments you have solved the problem, and you can work back along this table to find out where the segments are - or, if this is inconvenient, you can save extra information as you go along to make this easier.

I believe similar approaches will minimize the sum of absolute deviations, or minimize the maximum deviation at any point, subject to you being able to solve the corresponding problems for a single line. I have implicitly assumed you can fit a straight line to minimize the sum of squared errors, which is of course a standard sum of squares line fit. Minimizing the absolute deviations from a straight lines is an exercise in convex optimization which I would attempt by repeatedly weighted least squares. Minimizing the maximum absolute deviation is linear programming.